# 2 Elements next to image using Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get the following result (using flexbox)

[image]

This is what I'm getting using my code below

[image]

I'm using the following code, which is aligning the image but it's applying the align-items to all the items so the other h6 is also floating..

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="/img/person.jpg" />
  <h5>Jordan Baker</h5>
  <h6>Owner of Bavet</h6>
</div>
```

Am I missing something? Thank you

Comment: it's because your flex direction is row by default so all items will be lined up in columns, you either need to set a fixed height and change it to columns with wrap, or change the structure of your html

Comment: Here's an example using your html structure: https://jsfiddle.net/nzsr16n4.  I would probably go with the answer below though and change your html structure so it would be more flexible

Comment: The `<img>` tag does not need or use a closing slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your headings in another wrapper

```
<div class="block">
  <img src="/img/person.jpg" />
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h5>Jordan Baker</h5>
    <h6>Owner of Bavet</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With your provided markup, try the following

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 300px;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

h5, h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="/img/person.jpg" />
  <h5>Jordan Baker</h5>
  <h6>Owner of Bavet</h6>
</div>
```

`flex-direction` and `flex-wrap` along with `height` of the block are the attributes that will help achieve the required alignment.

Change the `margin`, `padding` etc attributes of the `h5`, `h6` or even the `.block` to your requirements.